# Spring LdapRepository returns no results while Spring Security works

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-ldap, spring-repositories

**My Problem**

I am using an LdapRepository to get user information from an Ldap server. This Ldap server is also queried by Spring Security to authenticate user.

My issue is, that Spring Security is able to find and identify users, while I'm unable to find users through my LdapRepository, using the same LdapContextSource. Querying the LdapRepository in any way does not return results (`null` or empty Lists).

**What I have tried**

- Using the [ldapsearch](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ldap-utils/ldapsearch.1.en.html) tool directly - *Works*
- Using `LdapQuery` instead of the `findByUsername` method - *Does not work*
- Testing methods like `findAll()` (`CrudRepository`) - *Returns an empty List*
- Trying to get logs from `spring-ldap` - [*Seems to be impossible?*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/issues/345)

Used ldapsearch command: `ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://<domain> -b o=<org> uid=<uid>`

Viewing the traffic in Wireshark (using `ldap` instead of `ldaps`) looks like no query is executed by the LdapRepository at all, the connection just opens and closes with 0 results.

**Relevant code**

Configuration of LdapContextSource

```
@Bean
public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl("ldaps://<domain>");
    contextSource.setBase("o=<org>");
    return contextSource;
}
```

SecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;

    private final LdapContextSource ldapContext;

    public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder, LdapContextSource ldapContext) {
        this.authenticationManagerBuilder = authenticationManagerBuilder;
        this.ldapContext = ldapContext;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            authenticationManagerBuilder
                    .ldapAuthentication()
                    .contextSource(ldapContext)
                    .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("Security configuration failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends LdapRepository<User> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
    List<User> findByUsernameLikeIgnoreCase(String username);
}
```

User

```
@Entry(
  objectClasses = {})
public class User {
    @Id
    private Name id;

    @Attribute(name = "uid", readonly = true)
    private String username;

    public Name getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Spring seems to assume the `objectClass` of `User` is `User`, if it is not set explicitly. Setting the correct objectClasses fixes this issue.